# Can I use ParameterizedTypeReference to avoid cast

Tags: java, spring, rest, generics, casting

I understand how to use ParameterizedTypeReference to influence RestTemplate deserialization, however, I would like to also have the return type dynamically determined as well.

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyModel>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyModel>>(){};
```

This the line I'd like to refactor:

```
ResponseEntity<List<MyModel>> = restTemplate.exchange(... typeRef)
```

Is there a form of `restTemplate.setExpectedReturnType(refType)` ?

Comment: I am trying to understand your question, but I can't. what is exactly the problem with `ResponseEntity<List<MyModel>> = restTemplate.exchange(... typeRef)`?

Comment: I'd like to dynamically assign the return type to correspond to the ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyModel>>